# Laravel 5.2 -> 5.3 Infinite Redirect Loop after upgrade

Tags: authentication, redirect, upgrade, laravel-5.3

I have [upgraded from Laravel 5.2 to 5.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0). All URI now lead to an infinite (`ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`) redirection loop at `/auth/login`. I tried to remove my middleware one after the other to try to find the problem. I even commented out the whole `Http\Kernel` and removed middleware from the `RouteServiceProviders`.

When I `artisan route:list`, I can see that now my routes have no middleware, but I still get the infinite redirection. For example, if I try to access a route without middleware `my.app/foo/bar` or use a random string `my.app/somerandomstringthatisnotaroute` I always get `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` at `my.app/auth/login`.

I also tried to `artisan clear-compiled` and `artisan route:clear`.

Comment: Have you tried to simply dd some output in your web.php (routes) ? Like Route::get('test', function() {dd('example');} - maybe use this as a first quick check

Comment: @FrankProvost I tried a bunch of things but after few hours I ended up reinstalling in a fresh install